# Retrieve list of songs ordered by last play time in iOS

Tags: ios, ipod, mpmediaquery

I need to obtain a list of the *N* most recently played songs from an iOS device, in order.

The only way I can imagine doing it, at the moment, is by getting all the songs through an `MPMediaQuery` and manually sort them by `lastPlayedDate`.

This is a potentially expensive operation and I was wondering if there was a better approach.

---

Edit: After some tests, this is a very expensive operation. On a test library of 2500 songs, it took around 20 seconds to:

1. Get all the songs.
2. Assign a date to all songs that had never played (January 1 1970).
3. Order them by date.
4. Fetch the first *N* entries.

Any suggestion of improvements would be appreciated.

---

Edit 2: Solved now, but just for the record here's what I was doing.

I was sorting using a block as described here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/805589/112702. Simply changing the sorting method to what's in Bryan's answer improved my speed by nearly 20 times on an iPod Touch 3.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

One way is to take the array of `MPMediaItem`s you get from the `MPMediaQuery` and sort it by `MPMediaItemPropertyLastPlayedDate` using an `NSSortDescriptor`:

```
NSTimeInterval start  = [[NSDate date] timeIntervalSince1970];

MPMediaQuery *songsQuery = [MPMediaQuery songsQuery];
NSArray *songsArray = [songsQuery items];

NSSortDescriptor *sorter = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:MPMediaItemPropertyLastPlayedDate
                                                         ascending:NO];
NSArray *sortedSongsArray = [songsArray sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:@[sorter]];

NSTimeInterval finish = [[NSDate date] timeIntervalSince1970];
NSLog(@"Execution took %f seconds.", finish - start);
```

This sorts the new array by most recently played first. I tested this on a iPhone 4S using 2000 songs and it took .98 seconds.

Comment: Thanks for that. Seems like the sorting method I was using had way too much overhead.

Answer (score 0):

I think `MPMediaQuery` is the only way to get recently played songs from an iOS device at this time.

You can use property `MPMediaItemPropertyLastPlayedDate`which will return you the most recent calendar date and time on which the user played the media item. Value is an `NSDate` object.

http://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/#documentation/MediaPlayer/Reference/MPMediaItem_ClassReference/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/constant_group/General_Media_Item_Property_Keys

Comment: That's what I tried, but it took much too long to execute. See updated post.