# Last heard songs (Swift)

Tags: ios, swift, mpmediaitem, mpmediaquery

I want to fill a `tableView` with the last heard songs. With `.nowPlayingItem` I can get the very last song, but how can I get the songs heard before?

I think this question already has an answer  at [Retrieve list of songs ordered by last play time in iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14651641/retreive-list-of-songs-ordered-by-last-play-time-in-ios), but it is in Objective-C and I´m not able to translate it. Or is there an even better way to do it in Swift instead?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
    let startTime: NSTimeInterval = NSDate().timeIntervalSince1970
    let songsQuery: MPMediaQuery = MPMediaQuery.songsQuery()
    let songsArray: [MPMediaItem] = songsQuery.items!
    let songsNSArray : NSArray = NSArray(array: songsArray)

    let descriptor: NSSortDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key: MPMediaItemPropertyLastPlayedDate, ascending: false)
    let sortedResults: NSArray = songsNSArray.sortedArrayUsingDescriptors([descriptor])


    let finishTime: NSTimeInterval = NSDate().timeIntervalSince1970
    NSLog("Execution took %f seconds to return %i results.", finishTime - startTime, sortedResults.count)
```

The results would be stored in the sortedResults array

Comment: To get something like title, you could simply use a loop to get `sortedResults[i].title`

Comment: great, which kind of loop?

Comment: Well, because you are doing this in a tableview, you should get the list of songs when the view loads (or somewhere outside of the cellForRowAtIndexPath).  Then, in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`, you would simply set the cell label to `sortedResults[indexPath.row].title`  If you need help implementing a `UITableView`, I would recommend moving that to a new question, as it is too broad to add here.

Comment: Do you know why it crashes when i try `sortedResults[indexPath.row].imageWithSize(imageSize)`? @wottle

Comment: You'd have to put a breakpoint and see the reason.  Are you sure all the songs have images. I don't think you can get the image straight from the `MPMediaItem` object.  I think you need to get the `MPMediaItemArtwork` property on the item.

Comment: No, not all songs have images. The log i get is `unrecognized selector sent to instance`. What do you suggest?

Comment: Do a google search on `MPMediaItemArtwork` and you will find out how to get it from the MPMediaItem object.  I think that is your problem.

Answer (score 3):

This is how you can do it in Swift,

```
let start = NSDate().timeIntervalSince1970

let songsQuery = MPMediaQuery.songsQuery()
if let songsArray = songsQuery.items {
    let sortedArray = songsArray.sort { item1, item2 in
        if let lastPlayedDateForItem1 = item1.lastPlayedDate, 
           let lastPlayedDateForItem2 = item2.lastPlayedDate {
            return lastPlayedDateForItem1.compare(lastPlayedDateForItem2) == .OrderedDescending
        }
        return false
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! How can i fill my tableView cells with it? Because `sortedArray` has no member like .title or .artist

Comment: For a large mdeia library, I would think that the `NSSortDescriptor` would be faster.  I can't confirm because I only have two songs on my device.  For a small library such as mine, it appears yours is faster.